# Why doesn't ReadTheDocs show "Last updated on"

Tags: configuration-files, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a [documentation](http://poc-library.readthedocs.io/) rendered by and hosted on ReadTheDocs. It still shows the Git commit hash instead of the "Last updated on" line, whereas my local HTML documentation shows today's date.

**Local version:**
[image]

**Online version:**
[image]

In the `docs/conf.py` file, I configured `html_last_updated_fmt` to a non `None` value -> empty string.
Source: https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L173-L176

Why is ReadTheDocs ignoring my setting? How can I get the last updated date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReadTheDocs default theme replaces the `Last updated` information with the revision info, if a revision info is available ([here's the commit that introduced the change](https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/pull/208/files)).

To fix this, you can create and use a custom theme.
This is not trivial. Proceed as follows:

- Fork the ReadTheDocs theme.
- "Undo" the changes of the commit I referenced above.
- Reference the fork in your documentation's `requirements` file. [Here](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/requirements/pip.txt), you can see an example of a requirements file. However, the file should typically be in the root directory of your repository and have the name `requirements.txt`.
- Make sure your project is configured to support the [installation of custom requirements](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html#understanding-what-s-going-on).
- Push all changes to GitHub.
- Rebuild your project on ReadTheDocs.